# append '__r' after the custom relationship name

Tags: relationships, custom

I have initiated a trigger on Sales_Order__c custom object. I want to upsert a lookup field - Order_History__c which is a link to OrderHistory (API name - Sales_Order__c) object. ID_Opp_Product_18__c, Sales_Order__c (referencing field in OpportunityLineItem), and Order_History__c are present as Custom Fields and Relationship in OpportunityLineItem. Here is my code:

```
trigger OrderHistory on Sales_Order__c (after insert)
{
     List<Sales_Order__c> so = [select Name, (select Sales_Order__c, OpportunityId, ID_Opp_Product_18__c from OpportunityLineItem) from Sales_Order__c where Name IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

     List<OpportunityLineItem> ol = new List<OpportunityLineItem>{};

     for(Sales_Order__c soc: so)
     {
          String s2 = String.valueOf(oli.Name);
          String s1 = s2.mid(2,8);
          for(OpportunityLineItem oli: soc.Sales_Order__c)
          {
              oli.Order_History__c = soc.Id;
              upsert oli;
          }
     }
}
```

I am getting a compile time error which says: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Sales_Order_*r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '*_r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
I am new to Salesforce and am not getting how and where exactly to append __r in my query to get this executed. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That implies you have a lookup from Sales_Order__c to OpportunityLineItem....i don't think that is possible. Do you mean you have a lookup from OpportunityLineItem to Sales Order?

Comment: yes, i have a lookup from OpportunityLineItem to SalesOrder.

Comment: Ok, so you have you're query the wrong way around.

List<OpportunityLineItem> ol = [ Select OpportunityId, ID_Opp_Product_18__c, Sales_Order__r.Name from OpportunityLineItem From OpportunityLineItem Where Sales_Order__c IN : Trigger.new ];

Comment: This is my initial code
trigger OrderHistory on Sales_Order__c (after insert) {

for (Sales_Order__c so : Trigger.new) 
{
String s2 = String.valueOf(so.Name);
String s1 = s2.mid(2,8);
if (s1!=null) {
List <OpportunityLineItem>  o1 = [select Sales_Order__c, OpportunityId, ID_Opp_Product_18__c from OpportunityLineItem
       where Sales_Order__c  =: s1];
     for(OpportunityLineItem o2 : o1) {
       IF(o1!=null){
        o2.Order_History__c  = so.Id;
        upsert o1;
       }
      } 
      } 
}
}
I was getting error-Too many DML rows:10001. So I am trying to bring SOQL out of the for loop.

Comment: That's a different error, thats because you're trying to update too many rows. You need to bulkify your trigger, there are lots of articles out there if you care to google.

Comment: As a solution to this error, i am trying to put the query out of the for loop, and i am up with the code that i have mentioned above. Here i am not able to understand how and where to append __r in my code. So we donot have to do anything with the governor limits error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on your requirements, but this may achieve what you are after. It should at the very least give you a rough idea on what is required to bulkify your trigger as mentioned by Phil.

```
trigger OrderHistory on Sales_Order__c (after insert) { 
    Map<String, ID> salesOrderMap = new Map<String, ID>();
    for (Sales_Order__c so : Trigger.new) { 
        String s2 = String.valueOf(so.Name); 
        String s1 = s2.mid(2,8); 
        if (s1 != null) {
            salesOrderMap.put(s1, so.Id);
        }
    }

    List <OpportunityLineItem> oppLineItems = [select Sales_Order__c, OpportunityId, ID_Opp_Product_18__c from OpportunityLineItem where Sales_Order__c In :salesOrderMap.keyset(); 
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : oppLineItems) { 
        ID salesOrderId = salesOrderMap.get(oli.Sales_Order__c);
        oli.Order_History__c = salesOrderId;
    }
    upsert oppLineItems;
}
```

NOTE: I apologize for any errors, I was unable to test as I don't have your schema.

Comment: Thank you luke.mcfarlane.. i tried using your approach and the records are getting updated without any error.. thank you so much..